# Just doing a test file in grails

Tags: grails

How can I create a simple testing/experimenting file in grails? I tried creating a TestController.groovy file in the /controllers folder, and then tried going to /project/Test/ but I get a 404.

In my TestController.groovy:

```
package aust

class TestController {
    def index = { 
      render {'Winning!... finally'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup a route to it correctly in your routing file? Also, you need to create an action in your controller, like `index`. Then, you should create a View in the Views folder, like `text\index.gsp`. I am a newbie too, but the [documentation is great for Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `TextController` and go to `/project/Test/` then there is an issue.
`------------------------------------------^-^`

go to

`/project/text/`

the url needs to match the name of the controller -- remember Grails is all about convention over configuration.

Also, make sure you have a default action on the controller, and any necessary gsps.

Comment: try going to /project/test/.  try going to /project/test/index.  try rendering the response as 'text/plain' also, edit your initial question

Comment: I had to go to project/test/ not project/Test/.  What do you want me to edit?

Comment: yeah, grails cares about the case in the url :(